# Can I share UWP viewmodels with xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.ios, xamarin.mac

What is realistic amount of code share between Xamarin and UWP?

I have app which has following layers:
1. UWP platform specific apis
2. Messaging protocol based on these apis
3. Services
4. ViewModels
5. Xaml Views communicating with INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand

I understand that obviously 1 (platform specific apis) an 5 (xaml views) cannot be shared. Layers 2 and 3 should be ok. What about ViewModels? I think it should be possible to achieve this using thin layer of viewModel adapter, is this realistic?

Also I am not planning to use xamarin.forms.

Comment: It depends ... but, when your iOS app will have the same view logic then the UWP app, then yes, they can be shared

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on your application.

UWP has many specific APIs that as such don't work on Xamarin. They are not necessary related to views only but can be also related to viewmodel code. If your viewmodel is a separate .Net standard project then you can reuse it completely, but as it is not always the case with UWP apps you can probably reuse just most of the code.

The second part comes down to actually using this viewmodel in iOS/macOS project. As you don't want to use XAML (Xamarin.Forms), there is no data binding provided. Basically you have to do whole data binding manually. Some MVVM frameworks may help you in that, but if you ask me they should be called 'helpers', not frameworks.

Comment: If your ViewModels contain platform related code then you have done something wrong.

Comment: @SirRufo not on UWP. For example there is UWP platform specific code for parsing RSS feeds, that is something that SHOULD belong to viewmodel. You may argue that Microsoft has done something wrong by making this platform specific, but that is out of scope to discuss here.

Comment: No, the Application-Layer defines a RSSParsingService interface which the ViewModels can use but that concrete service is implemented in the Infrastructure-Layer or in the UWP project (choose which fits best)

Comment: @SirRufo if your original scope of the project was to support UWP there is nothing wrong in not doing so. Again all Microsoft examples work like that. If you want to prove that you may have a separate opinion you may. But it is NOT a UWP development standard.

Comment: Calm down. I know there is a gap between the theory and practice. A lot of apps and examples (even from MS) are using short cuts, just to get the job done and and break up with the theory. But there is no reason to do so except too less time for design. BTW: I also use such shortcuts from time to time, but I know these are only shortcuts and not as it should be. So I know when I do something wrong and I know why (less time)

Comment: @IvanIčin I kind of excluded Xamarin.Forms, because I have heard too many bad opinions on them, and I thought that binds to native code (like xamarin.mac) cannot be messed up. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Shadow this site is not for opinions, and what you ask now is an opinion. There are always pros and cons and it is up to you to see what is the best for you as only you know your project. Saying that Xamarin.Forms is perfect or bad would be both wrong for sure.

Comment: @IvanIčin my question is more like "is it good enough". Because if it is good enough I can just use my view models and bind to them, right?

Comment: @Shadow if it is good enough, yes. I can’t say what is good enough. You will have limitations that can have workarounds which may be more or less complex. How do you expect me to say how it relates to your project? How can I know which limitations are fine for you and which are not?

Comment: @IvanIčin can you point me to place where I can read about these limitations? Basically this is root behind this question, I expected someone to point out that there may be some problems with VM sharing.